# Выбранный путь некорректно вносится в БД

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

В программе есть OpenFileDialog. В нем я выбираю путь и вношу в переменную route. В route путь вносится так, как надо, а именно *'E:/papka/file.docx'*. В базу путь вносится уже неправильно, а именно *'E:papkafile.docx'.*
Как сделать так, чтобы путь вносился в базу корректно?
Код на добавление записи в БД:

```
DBConnection.MyCommand.CommandText = @"insert into document values(null,'" + route + "','" + klient + "','" + worker + "','" + data1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "')";
                                        if (DBConnection.MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                                        {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                        else { return false; }
```

Comment: Ну вроде бы очевидно - слэш воспринимается как экранирующий символ, и потому удаляется при подстановке в текст запроса (проверьте `DBConnection.MyCommand.CommandText` сразу после присвоения). Заквотируйте его (замените на `\/` либо удвойте - я не в курсе, как правильно).

Comment: @Akina Получилось с заменой слэша на двойной. Спасибо!

Comment: А еще лучше используйте параметризированные запросы